# How to specify methods to be skipped by Sonar when counting coverage?

Tags: code-coverage, static-analysis, sonarqube

I am using sonar for code analysis in my current project and my question is how can I specify certain methods, particularly getters and setters to be excluded when counting code coverage.

Also I realized that for the @Component and @Value annotations the line coverage is 0, even when there is a unit test which uses the specific bean. Interestingly, the @Autowired is skipped as it should be.

Where can I change this configuration/add some exceptions?

Comment: You could comment out the methods to be skipped :-) Seriously though, if the code is present why would you not want it to be counted? You're altering the metric and changing it's meaning.... BTW I fully understand the over-fixation and unfair pressure posed by uninformed non-techies interpreting code coverage metrics....

Comment: Yes that is exactly the reason, my team is receiving ridiculous expectations from QA regarding coverage numbers and I need to explain why 60% is actually a really good result.

Comment: This is why some teams spend time generating Junit tests that invoke unused methods. Hilariously this counter-balances Eclipse code generation of getter and setter methods.... Java is just too verbose! I'm on your side, but.... QA does have a point. If the method is uncovered, it is therefore unused, perhaps it should be removed :-(

Comment: If you just want to get easy coverage on your bean, try JavaBeanTester: explained here: http://codebox.org.uk/pages/articles/unit-testing-javabeans and the code is here: https://github.com/codebox/javabean-tester - it will get you close to 100% coverage on your beans (it doesn't test toString() and it can't instantiate all types of getters and setters) It is a really easy way to get coverage on your beans.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77260395/865033

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's currently no way to do exclude specific methods from code coverage.

For your second case, the problem is not on Sonar side but on the coverage tool that you use (Cobertura by default, but you may have changed it to Jacoco, Emma or Clover). You can try all those different tools to see which one gives you the best results. FYI, Jacoco will soon be the default coverage tool for Sonar.

Comment: wasn't exactly the answer I was hoping for but now at least I won't spend hours with finding a solution :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Just wanna see if anything has changed. I'm trying to exclude certain lines of code (entire methods works too though)

Since 2012, anything related to exclusion is documented in:

- "[Analysis scope / Code coverage exclusion](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/project-administration/analysis-scope/#code-coverage-exclusion)" (Sonar 10.x)
- "[Narrowing the focus / Code coverage exclusion](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.9/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#code-coverage-exclusion)" (Sonar 8.x/9.x)

For instance:

```ini
# sonar-project.properties
sonar.coverage.exclusions=**/*Getter.java,**/*Setter.java
```

That will exclude all files that end with `Getter` or `Setter`. You can also use other tools or plugins like Jacoco to exclude those methods by annotation or pattern, and then import the Jacoco report into SonarQube. See the [Lombok Annotation Type Generated](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/Generated).

See "[Sonar Skipping Method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76722069/6309)" to define comment patterns to stop and restart sonar processing and then use those comments around the method you want to ignore.

[This thread](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonar-ignore-issues-by-block-not-working/27008/6) shows the UI:

[image: https://europe1.discourse-cdn.com/sonarsource/uploads/sonarcommunity/optimized/3X/5/0/50216548db11ff899516c21b4461e76f67d577f0_2_690x184.png]

> An example of the code where the @SONAR_STOP and @SONAR_START comments are embedded :
>
> ```cpp
> /**
>  * Close the container.
>  */
> public static void shutdown() {
>     if (postgresContainer != null) { // @SONAR_STOP@
>         postgresContainer.close();
>         postgresContainer = null;
>     }
> } // @SONAR_START@
> ```
>
> I also tried this code but it didn’t work:
>
> ```cpp
> /**
>  * Close the container.
>  */
> public static void shutdown() {
>     // @SONAR_STOP@
>     if (postgresContainer != null) {
>         postgresContainer.close();
>         postgresContainer = null;
>     }
> }
> // @SONAR_START@
> ```