# Sonar Skipping Method

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube

I have a java project with sonarqube on, and currently we also have one method that should be excluded from tests. I understand for one liners, we could annotate `//NOSONAR`, but what is a good way to skip code coverage scanning for one entire method? I am using springboot, is there some annotation or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sonar.issue.ignore.block` config to define comment patterns to stop and restart sonar processing and then use those comments around the method you want to ignore.

With the `sonarqube` gradle plugin, the config could look like below:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.issue.ignore.block', 'e1'
        property 'sonar.issue.ignore.block.e1.beginBlockRegexp', '@sonar-stop'
        property 'sonar.issue.ignore.block.e1.endBlockRegexp', '@sonar-start'
    }
}
```

Then the usage would look something like below:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Log 1");
        
    // @sonar-stop
    System.out.println("Log 2");
    System.out.println("Log 3");
        
    // @sonar-start
    System.out.println("Log 4");
}
```

Now the second and third print statements won't be detected as issues by sonar.

Comment: What's the significance of e1?

Comment: From what I could tell, it is just an identifier for a block config that we can then use to define the stop and start comment patterns. It can be named anything else as well